# Entity framework automation migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I used to use the command to command line in Entity Framework, which automatically creates models and contexts from the database, I can't find it, could anyone remember remember to link to it?

Comment: It is `scaffold-dbcontext` then you have to pass in connection string, sql driver (i.e 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'), and output directory. Example: `Scaffold-DbContext "*connection*" "*provider*" -OutputDir "BackendProject" -ContextDir "DbContexts"`

Comment: Also very useful is the -Tables option which allows you to pick which tables you want in the resultant model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mean scaffolding? see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding

with .NET cli:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Chinook" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Scaffold-DbContext` command.

Here is a nice tutorial about [creating your model from existing DB in net core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx).

A big change though, the old-style EDMX way doesn't exist anymore. As the tutorial says in the end:

> Note: Once you have created the model, you must use the Migration
>   commands whenever you change the model to keep the database up to date
>   with the model.